# Oracle SQL problem with declare variable from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with make variable from table.

```
DECLARE
 liczba1 PLS_INTEGER;
 
 BEGIN
Select liczba1 := MAX(EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM PRACOWNICY;
 
 END;
```

That is the problem

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

I don't have any idea why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `into`:

```
SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_ID) INTO liczba1 FROM PRACOWNICY
```